# The spectrum and the tangent space of the algebra of holomorphic functions on a Stein manifold

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

Let $A$ be a [Fréchet algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_algebra) over ${\mathbb C}$, and let us call the *spectrum* ${\tt Spec}[A]$ of $A$ the set of all characters, i.e. continuous multiplicative linear functionals $s:A\to{\mathbb C}$, endowed with some natural topology, say, the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets in $A$. For each $s\in{\tt Spec}[A]$ let us call a *tangent space* in $s$, ${\tt T}_s[A]$, the set of all tangent vectors in $s$, i.e. continuous linear functionals $\tau:A\to{\mathbb C}$ such that 
$$
\tau(f\cdot g)=s(f)\cdot\tau(g)+\tau(f)\cdot s(g),\qquad f,g\in A
$$
(again, we endow ${\tt T}_s[A]$ with some natural topology, say, the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets in $A$).

Let $M$ be a [Stein manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stein_manifold) and $A={\mathcal O}(M)$, the algebra of holomorphic functions on $M$ (with the usual topology of uniform convergence on compact sets in $M$).

I believe that 
$$
{\tt Spec}[{\mathcal O}(M)]\cong M,
$$
(a homeomorphism of topological spaces), and for each $s\in M$
$$
{\tt T}_s[{\mathcal O}(M)]\cong{\tt T}_s(M)
$$
(an isomorphism with the usual tangent space of $M$ in the point $s\in M$), but I can't find a reference. Can anybody help me?

EDIT. Ben McKay gave a reference for the first equality, so it remains to prove the second one. As far as I understand, here everything follows from the following variant of

> [Hadamard's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_lemma): Let $s$ be a point on a Stein manifold $M$, and $f_1,...,f_n\in {\mathcal O}(M)$ a sequence of functions which form local coordinates in a neighbourhood of $s$ and
>   $$
> f_1(s)=...=f_n(s)=0
> $$
>   (such $f_k$ always exist). Then for every function $f\in{\mathcal O}(M)$ there exist functions $g_1,...,g_m,h_1,...,h_m\in {\mathcal O}(M)$ such that 
>   $$
> g_1(s)=...=g_m(s)=h_1(s)=...=h_m(s)=0
> $$
>   and
>   $$
> f=f(s)+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial f_k}(s)\cdot f_k+
> \sum_{k=1}^m g_k\cdot h_k
> $$
>   where $\frac{\partial f}{\partial f_k}(s)$ are partial derivatives in $s$ along the coordinates $f_k$.

That is not true?

Answer (score 2):

The statement that $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}(M)=M$ on a complex manifold $M$ whose holomorphic functions separate points precisely when $M$ is a Stein manifold is in H. Rossi, *On envelops of holomorphy*, **Communications in Pure and Applied Mathematics**, XVI, 1963, 9-17, theorem 2.6 page 10.

Comment: Rossi persistently misspells the noun "envelope" as the verb "envelop".

Comment: Ah, OK! And what about the tangent space?

Comment: There is no such description of the tangent space in Rossi's paper. I don't know a reference.

Comment: Ben, I can't get this paper. Does Rossi prove the homeomorphism of topological spaces or just the equality of sets?

Comment: In the middle of the proof, he says it is a homeomorphism and explains why.

Comment: The aptly-titled book "Theory of Stein Spaces" discusses full faithfulness for the functor $X\rightsquigarrow O(X)$ from general Stein spaces (could be singular, or non-reduced) into a suitable category of Frechet $\mathbf{C}$-algebras. The desired definition of the tangent space consists of the continuous $\mathbf{C}$-algebra maps $O(M)\rightarrow \mathbf{C}[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^2)$ lifting evaluation at $s$, so by full faithfulness (!) these correspond to maps of analytic spaces ${\rm{Spec}}(\mathbf{C}[\epsilon]/(\varepsilon^2))\rightarrow M$ lifting $s$. Working locally at $s$, we win.

Comment: @nfdc23, is it possible that this is simpler? Let $I_s$ be the ideal of functions in ${\mathcal O}(M)$ vanishing at the point $s\in M$. Actually, I need the following: if  a system of functions $f_1,...,f_n\in {\mathcal O}(M)$ form local coordinates in a point $s\in M$ and $f_1(s)=...=f_n(s)=0$, then for any  $f\in {\mathcal O}(M)$ the function $f-f(s)-\lambda_1 f_1-...-\lambda_n f_n$ belongs to $(I_s)^2$, where $\lambda_i$ are the partial derivatives of $f$ in the point $s$ along the coordinates $f_i$. Is this true?

Comment: I  had tried exactly the same idea before writing the comment that I did.  It doesn't seem to be possible to make that more concrete argument work since typically such $f_j$'s will have common zeros elsewhere (even if a discrete locus of such).  Or at least I didn't see a way to get around that issue (one can try to increase the number of $f_j$'s, but then one loses contact with the "local coordinates" near $s$ aspect).  But I agree that there should be a more elementary argument without bringing in a non-reduced space (the fat point).

Comment: Actually, I don't understand... For which Stein manifold $N$ we have ${\mathcal O}(N)={\mathbb C}[\varepsilon]/\varepsilon^2$?

Comment: There is no such manifold: it is a 1-point Stein space in the wider sense of complex-analytic spaces (which may be singular or even have non-reduced structure sheaf) and has a 1-dimensional tangent space with preferred basis (dual to $\varepsilon$). Complex-analytic spaces are the analytic counterpart to schemes, and provide a more robust framework for developing both coherent sheaf theory and analytic geometry (much as singular varieties are useful in algebraic geometry, when making intersections or forming zero loci); they are developed from scratch in the book "Coherent Analytic Sheaves".